# Advise on Directory stucture

Tags: jquery, html, css, web

been a while, getting back on the horse after a small break. I have a question..

I have a simple website running some simple jquery scripts, I have a sub directory and I am wondering if it is best to duplicate the java and css into the sub directory, or to link back to my main directory. I ask in terms of speed really, but also at this point would save me some hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good nesting is like this:

```
root/
L index.html
L js/
L images/
L css/
L contact/   <-A sub-webpage
```

The page .html in contact/ should use a absolute link to find the javascripts like:

`<script src="//js/bootstrap.js"></script>`

Also, **Java** does **NOT** = **JavaScript**